# UISearchDisplayController without a UITableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

Is it possible to implement a UISearchDisplayController without a UITableView? Or at least hide the TableView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create an instance of UISearchBar in your view and implement the UISearchBarDelegate protocol.  Make sure your view is set as the delegate for the search bar as well.  When the user clicks the done button it will send a message to the delegate method searchBarSearchButtonClicked:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.searchBar.delegate = self;
}

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    // Handle search request
}
```

You just need to either place the UISearchBar in your nib file or place it programmatically.

Comment: The problem I'm I having is when you switch uiviewcontroller to ustableviewcontroller your app crashes immediately